ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure' 表示されて何が足りないのか分からない
OSをRHEL7.9からRHEL8.9に移行し、Pythonのスクリプトを実行したところ下記エラーで動作しない状況です。
エラーメッセージ:
from azure.monitor.query import MetricsQueryClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'

事前にMSから必要と言われた下記はインストール済みです。

azure-identity 1.17.1
azure-monitor-query 1.4.0

「azure 5.0.0」が足りていないのか、パッケージを落として試したところ非推奨でインストールできないとエラーが表示されて、個別でインストールする必要があるようで何が足りていなくて動作しないのか判断がつきません。
ソースコード:
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import sys
import datetime
from azure.monitor.query import MetricsQueryClient

import os
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "10.20.1.1:8080"
os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = "10.20.1.1:8080"
os.environ["https_proxy"] = "10.20.1.1:8080"
os.environ["http_proxy"] = "10.20.1.1:8080"

args = sys.argv
resource_group_name = args[1]  # Azure Resource Group name
rs_name = args[2]  # Azure SQL Managed Instance name
mtrx_name = args[3]  # Azure SQL Managed Instance Monitoring metric name
subscription_id = args[4]  # Subscription-ID

agr_type = 'Average'

resource_id = (
    f"subscriptions/{subscription_id}/"
    f"resourceGroups/{resource_group_name}/"
    f"providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/{rs_name}"
)

#create client
TENANT_ID = ''
CLIENT = ''
KEY = ''

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = CLIENT,
    secret = KEY,
    tenant = TENANT_ID
)

client = MonitorManagementClient(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)

nowtm = datetime.datetime.now()
justnowt = nowtm - datetime.timedelta(hours=9)
justnowt = justnowt - datetime.timedelta(minutes=4)
oneminbef = justnowt - datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

metrics_data = client.query(
    resource_id,
    metric_names=[mtrx_name],
    start_time=oneminbef,
    end_time=justnowt,
    interval='PT1M',
    aggregation=agr_type
)

for item in metrics_data:
    for timeserie in item.timeseries:
        for data in timeserie.data:
            print(format(data.average))


Azure SDK for Python のドキュメントを見る限り、Python 3.8 以降が必要なようです。
スクリプトでは Python 3.6 を指定しているようなので、まずはここを見直してみてください。

Prerequisites
The client libraries are supported on Python 3.8 or later.

また、単に azure という名前で提供されていたパッケージは 5.0 で非推奨となっているようです。
"azure" と接頭辞の付くパッケージを必要に応じて個別にインストールするようです。

Starting with v5.0.0, this package is deprecated. Please install the service specific packages prefixed by azure needed for your application.


質問時点での説明不足ですみません。pythonについては3.8をインストールして、動作確認しています。MS側から3.8がモジュールの動作条件と聞いております。必要とされるモジュールをインストールしている認識でいるのですが、それでもエラーが出ているので何が足りないのか分からない状況です。

ソースコードの一番頭に #!/usr/bin/env python3.6 とありますが、ここでPythonのバージョンが指定されているので、ここを3.8を指定するように変更すると良いと思います

返信が遅くなり、すみません。ありがとうございます。
